# Matching Error Level in FindBugs IntelliJ and Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, findbugs

I'm running FindBugs in Maven and my IntelliJ. I'd like to ensure that executing FindBugs in either tool results in the same analysis. It'd be confusing to developers if IntelliJ and Maven output different errors/warnings when running the static analysis tool.

**Maven**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </plugin>
```

**FindBugs-IDEA Setup**

[image: Configuration]

I see that FindBugs can be configured in Maven with different `Thresholds` and `Efforts`, but how can I synchronize IntelliJ's and Maven's FindBugs config?

Example:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
      <effort>Max</effort>
      <threshold>Low</threshold>
    ...
  </plugin>
```

http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/examples/violationChecking.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Settings (Control + Alt + S)
2. Go to FindBugs
3. Click Advanced (requires scrolling down in a tab - look at red boxed area in the below screenshot)
4. Set `Analysis Effort` based on POM `effort`
5. Set `Confidence Level` based on POM `threshold`

[image: Advanced]